# How to call a double from another method?

Tags: java

I'm new to coding and I'm having trouble with trying to get a double from another method. In trying to make it so I can set the length, width, and height of a cube and it outputs these numbers and the area, but I can't get one of my methods to take the math problem I made?

Cube.java

```
public class Cube {


    public double height;
    public double width;
    public double length;


    static void CalculateTotalArea(double height, double width, double length) {
        double area = (double) (height * width * length);
   
    }
 

    public void printWords(){
        System.out.println("This cube has a height of " + height + 
            " , a width of " + width + 
            " , and a depth of " + length + 
            ". Its total area is: " + area);
    }  
}
```

What I'm trying to do in `printWords`, is have it print the numbers type and show the area but it won't take my area from the math problem above it.

I don't know if you need to see the other class to understand what I'm doing so I'm just gonna post that too.

Lab5.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Please type the Height, Width, and Length"
            + " of the cube you would like to see the area of."
            + " For example 10 5 2");
    
    // allows "scan(Hight, Width, and Length)" to be given a typed number
    double scanHeight = scanner.nextInt();
    double scanWidth = scanner.nextInt();
    double scanLength = scanner.nextInt();        
    
    Cube finalCube = new Cube();
    finalCube.height = scanHeight;
    finalCube.width = scanWidth;
    finalCube.length = scanLength;
    Cube.CalculateTotalArea(finalCube.height, finalCube.width, finalCube.length); 
    finalCube.printWords();
      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you didn't declare an instance variable `area` in the `Cube` class. That's why you are facing error.

I have updated the code to this :

```
public class Cube {

    public double height;
    public double width;
    public double length;

    public double calculateTotalArea(double height, double width, double length) {
        return (height * width * length);

    }

    public void printWords() {
        System.out.println("This cube has a height of " + height + " , a width of " + width + " , and a depth of "
                + length + ". Its total area is: " + calculateTotalArea(height, width, length));
    }
}
```

Update main method to this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please type the Height, Width, and Length"
                + " of the cube you would like to see the area of." + " For example 10 5 2");

        // allows "scan(Hight, Width, and Length)" to be given a typed number
        double scanHeight = scanner.nextInt();
        double scanWidth = scanner.nextInt();
        double scanLength = scanner.nextInt();

        Cube finalCube = new Cube();
        finalCube.height = scanHeight;
        finalCube.width = scanWidth;
        finalCube.length = scanLength;
        finalCube.printWords();

    }
```

That's all.

Comment: Why `calculateTotalArea` is public ?

Comment: @FSm I kept public if he wants to use that method for some other purpose in the code.

Comment: Thank you and everyone with helping me with this I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You are making several mistakes here

- Your code should not compile. In your `printWords()` you didn't define the `area`
- You are assigning the calculated area to a local variable. So your print method does have scope to get that.

Change your `Cube.java` to this

```
public class Cube {

    public double height;
    public double width;
    public double length;

    public double area;

    public void calculateTotalArea() {
        this.area = this.height * this.width * this.length;
    }

    public void printWords() {
        System.out.println("This cube has a height of " + height +
                " , a width of " + width +
                " , and a depth of " + length +
                ". Its total area is: " + area);
    }
}
```

And call the calculate method by instance

```
finalCube.calculateTotalArea();
finalCube.printWords();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are not storing the area calculated in any field in `Cube` class so when you are calling the `printWords` function, at that time, the value in the area is not defined.

The scope of the `area` variable is limited to `CalculateTotalArea` function. You can't use it in `printWords`.

Try this to solve the problem:

1. Define a new field in the same class named `area`.
2. In the `CalculateTotalArea` function, remove the `double` keyword and make area to `this.area`.
3. Replace similarly in `printWords` function, `area` to `this.area`.
4. Instead of calling as static function, use the object to call the `printWords` function.

`finalCube.CalculateTotalArea(finalCube.height, finalCube.width, finalCube.length);`

So, after the final changes, it looks like this:

```
public class Cube {

public double height;
public double width;
public double length;
public double area;

static void CalculateTotalArea(double height, double width, double length) {
    this.area = (double) (height * width * length);
   
}

public void printWords(){
    System.out.println("This cube has a height of " + height + 
            " , a width of " + width + 
            " , and a depth of " + length + 
            ". Its total area is: " + this.area);
   }  

}
```

And change your Lab5.java to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Please type the Height, Width, and Length"
            + " of the cube you would like to see the area of."
            + " For example 10 5 2");
    
    // allows "scan(Hight, Width, and Length)" to be given a typed number
    double scanHeight = scanner.nextInt();
    double scanWidth = scanner.nextInt();
    double scanLength = scanner.nextInt();        
    
    Cube finalCube = new Cube();
    finalCube.height = scanHeight;
    finalCube.width = scanWidth;
    finalCube.length = scanLength;
    finalCube.CalculateTotalArea(finalCube.height, finalCube.width, finalCube.length); 
    finalCube.printWords();
      
}
```

Other suggestions, just for good practices:

1. Define a constructor for your `Cube` class.

   Class(int h, int w, int l){
   this.height = h;
   this.width = w;
   this.length = l;
   }
2. While making a new instance of `Cube`, using this constructor.

`Cube finalCube = new Cube(scanHeight, scanWidth, scanLength);`